Facing error while deploying static react web app at azure
Can anyone tell me how to see these logs enter image description here
I think error was in giving the path to source code and build .
So my folder structure looks like thisenter image description here
What error I am facing ?

Log in to the Azure Portal. Navigate to the Resource Group which your app is being deployed to. Select Deployments from the navigation blade. You should see a failed deployment in there. Click on it and you should be able to get more detailed logs.
